# What is the difference between the two methods Document.SaveAs2 Document.WdSaveFormat

Tags: vba, ms-word

What is the difference between the two methods    Document.SaveAs2   Document.WdSaveFormat

Comment: `WdSaveFormat` is not a method. It is an enumeration used in the `SaveAs2` and `SaveAs` method. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdsaveformat?view=word-pia

Answer (score 0):

The [Document.SaveAs2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Word.SaveAs2) method saves the specified document with a new name or format. Some of the arguments for this method correspond to the options in the Save As dialog box (File tab).

The [WdSaveFormat enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdsaveformat) specifies the format to use when saving a document.

```
Sub SaveAsRTF() 
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:="Text.rtf", _ 
        FileFormat:=wdFormatRTF 
End Sub
```